# Faulted phase detection

Tags: short-circuit, three-phase, fault

Currently I am studying about short circuit detection on long lines and I can't solve one task:

I have line between two substations, and there is short circuit some where on this line. I know current and voltage which are measured at one of substations:

- Voltage in phases is in complex form (\$V_a = 72\angle 0^\circ \$, \$V_b = 19\angle-137^\circ\$, \$V_c = 18\angle121^\circ\$)
- Second sequence voltage is \$V_2 = 19\angle177^\circ\$
- Zero sequence voltage is \$V_0 = 16.8\angle1^\circ\$
- Current in phases is in complex form (\$I_a = 0.1\angle140^\circ\$, \$I_b = 1.4\angle-1^\circ\$, \$I_c = 1.4\angle-139^\circ\$)
- Second sequence current is \$I_2 = 0.6\angle-70^\circ\$
- Zero sequence current is \$3*I_0 = 1\angle-70^\circ\$

So I know that if there is zero sequence current it means, that it is one phase fault, but I cant understand which phase is connected to ground.

Comment: What do these values come from? Reality? Simulation? Is the network solid grounded? What assumptions have been made (line capacitances)? How much are they accurate? The presence of zero-sequence voltage does not necessarily mean it is one-phase fault, but that there is a non-symmetrical fault with earth (can be two-phase) or there is a gap in the line (broken conductor). I think it is B-C-Earth fault because there is no current Ia.

Comment: Power system analysis questions like this would be a good fit for the proposed "Electrical Power Engineering" Stack Exchange - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59748/electrical-power-engineering .

Comment: @Li-aungYip The "Electrical Power Engineering" Stack Exchange" is no more.